# Is this mold on my wood window frame? What should I do about it?

Tags: windows, window-frame

Is this mold on my wood window frame? It is several years old and I have noticed tiny black specs that have grown over the last few years?

Everyone says "use bleach" but that doesn't seem right--this mold is *in* the wood, not on top of it.

What should I do about it?  I hope I don't have to replace the window.  Is there a way to restore it?  If so, how do I find the right person to hire for it?

[image: Window Frame 1]

[image: Window Frame 2]

Answer (score 0):

It does look like mold, most likely from internal condensation forming on the cold widow frame. You could try just wiping it with a rag that has some mold / mildew remover on it, like the stuff you use in baths and showers (Tilex, X-14, etc.), or even make your own diluted solution of laundry breach and water (1 cup per gallon of water). Wear gloves and don't get it on your clothes, bleach will bleach...

Comment: Will that soak into the wood or otherwise hurt it?

Comment: No more than any other cleaner would. Wipe it on, wait a minute or two, then wipe it off.

Comment: But bleach will discolor the wood, I believe.

Comment: Maybe, but it is already discolored (black spots)

Comment: I would not use anything with bleach in it on wood.  Besides the discoloration problem, bleach does not penetrate wood.  So a bleach treatment may remove the surface mold, but will not kill the "root" of the mold down in the wood fibers and so the mold will just grow back.

Answer (score -2):

What climate do you live in? Moisture goes from high to low moisture and if you are getting mold growing that means the moisture barrier is not setup properly. You should be worried about mold it can kill your house.